# To solve $dy/dx=g(y),$ we can instead solve $dx/dy=1/g(y).$ But, does this even work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In order to solve the DE $$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$$

I always appeal to the fact that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y) \Leftrightarrow \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{g(y)}.$$

But, is this even a fact?! I seem to recall that $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1} = \frac{dx}{dy}$$ only under certain circumstances, so that we lose generality by using this equivalence. If so, then how are we meant to obtain the most general solution to the original DE?

Comment: Yes, this will work to solve for $x$ as a function of $y$. Then you have to find the inverse of the result to get $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: It is, under appropriate conditions on $g$, a fact. Depending on $g$, there is potential trouble with division by $0$. More or less equivalently, we have $\int\frac{dy}{g(y)}=\int dx$.

Comment: The fact is usually proven using the inverse function theorem, which means that you can only find a local solution on an open neighborhood where $g$ does not vanish.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fact. What you are assuming is that $y$ is an invertible function of $x$. This assumption requires that $g(y)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\neq0$. Inverting this into a function $x$ of $y$ we get by the Inverse Function Theorem:

$\frac{dx(y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}=\frac{1}{g(y)}$.

From here, as the comment section suggests, you simply integrate both sides to solve the differential equation:

$x=\int dx=\int\frac{dx}{dy}dy=\int \frac{1}{g(y)}dy$.

Comment: But that means we havent found the most general solution to the original DE.

Comment: It won't usually produce the most general solution. Usually this trick is applied when we have enough information on $g$ to conclude that the general solution can be found this way.

Comment: What sort of information on $g$? I mean, assuming that $g$ never vanishes, what else do we need?

Comment: I think the condition of $g$ not vanishing is enough since then $y$ is monotone.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. I will write a CW answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is both continuous and non-vanishing, then no generality is lost.

To see this, assume that $g$ is a total function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is indeed both continuous and non-vanishing. Then $g$ must be strictly positive everywhere, or else strictly negative everywhere.

In the first case, every solution $y$ to the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$$ is strictly increasing hence injective. For every solution, by continuity, we have that $y(\mathbb{R})$ is an interval and since every $y$ is injective then we have a continuous inverse to each $y$ defined on the interval $y(\mathbb{R})$. For every solution $y$ we have $y$ is differentiable at each point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with non-zero derivative so the inverse will be differentiable at $y(x)$ and will satisfy $\frac{dx}{dy}\vert_{y(x)}=\frac{1}{\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\vert_{x}\big)}$. But this implies that $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1} = \frac{dx}{dy}.$$ A similar argument can be in the second case.

So, at least if $g$ is continuous and non-vanishing (and defined on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$), no generality is lost.